# Keras: training performance are different with exact same data and architecture. The only difference is using .Sequential() or .Model()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

the model below is from `Keras` [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_regression) and it behaves exactly as expected. It is defined with `keras.models.Sequential()`. I want to convert it to be defined with `keras.models.Model()` to make it more flexible for my future use. But after my conversion, the performance plummeted.

The original model you can find on `Keras` website:

```
def build_model():
  model = Sequential([
    layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]),
    layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    layers.Dense(1)
  ])

  optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()
  model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
  return model

model = build_model()
model.summary()

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_22 (Dense)             (None, 64)                640       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)             (None, 64)                4160      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_24 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 65        
=================================================================
Total params: 4,865
Trainable params: 4,865
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The following code is my conversion:

```
def build_model_base():
  input = Input(shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())])
  x = Dense(64, activation='relu', name="dense1")(input)   
  x = Dense(64, activation='relu', name="dense2")(x)
  output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='output')(x)
  model = Model(input=[input], output=[output])
  optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam()

  model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
                optimizer=optimizer,
                metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'])
  return model

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_18 (InputLayer)        (None, 9)                 0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense1 (Dense)               (None, 64)                640       
_________________________________________________________________
dense2 (Dense)               (None, 64)                4160      
_________________________________________________________________
output (Dense)               (None, 1)                 65        
=================================================================
Total params: 4,865
Trainable params: 4,865
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The only difference I can see is `.Sequential` doesn't count `input layer` while `.Model` counts it, but I don't believe they make the model structure different. However, the performance of `.Sequential` is:

[image]

While the performance of the `.Model()` I converted is:

[image]

#### Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

#### Some other context:

I have read this [post](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8001), but my code are all run on CPU in Google Colab

`print(keras.__version__) # 2.0.4`

`print(tf.__version__) #1.14.0-rc1`

Code to plot the losses:

```
def plot_history(history):
  hist = pd.DataFrame(history.history)
  hist['epoch'] = history.epoch

  plt.figure()
  plt.xlabel('Epoch')
  plt.ylabel('Mean Abs Error [MPG]')
  plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['mean_absolute_error'],
           label='Train Error')
  plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['val_mean_absolute_error'],
           label = 'Val Error')
  y_max = max(hist['val_mean_absolute_error'])
  plt.ylim([0,y_max])
  plt.legend()

  plt.figure()
  plt.xlabel('Epoch')
  plt.ylabel('Mean Square Error [$MPG^2$]')
  plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['mean_squared_error'],
           label='Train Error')
  plt.plot(hist['epoch'], hist['val_mean_squared_error'],
           label = 'Val Error')
  y_max = max(hist['val_mean_squared_error'])
  plt.ylim([0,y_max])
  plt.legend()
  plt.show()
```

Code to train the model(it's exact same for both models):

```
his_seq = model.fit(normed_train_data.values, train_labels.values,
          batch_size=128,
          validation_split = 0.1,
          epochs = 100,
          verbose=0)
plot_history(his_seq)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: You added `sigmoid` activation in `Model`. In `Sequential`, it is defined with `linear` activation

Comment: Thank you @mlRocks! Yes, that's where I did wrong. The performance are same now once I removed the sigmoid activation from the `.Model`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Linear' activation function is used by default in the dense layer of keras, as well as the output layer of the sequential model you built.

But you specify the activation function as 'sigmoid' in your conversion, which may make a difference.

Here is the description about the default activation function provided by Keras:

```
activation: Activation function to use (see activations). If you don't specify anything, no activation is applied (ie. "linear" activation: a(x) = x).
```

Comment: Thank you so much @peilun! It fixed my problem, it never came to my mind. also I didn't know that activation function can make the performance worse. Appreciated a lot!